# Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running error while shutdown tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

Hi I am trying to shutdown and startup tomcat server. But i am getting below error while running shutdown.sh. Please check below error and suggest me to complete.

Error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-ju                                                                                        li.jar
Jul 24, 2017 11:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Jul 24, 2017 11:01:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.ja                                                                                        va:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocket                                                                                        Impl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java                                                                                        :188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
```

Also please find log:

```
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.884 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.884 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.884 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.884 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.988 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.990 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.992 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Jul-2017 23:48:28.992 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: You can't have both these conditions at the same time. Probably the bind error happened first, so Tomcat shut itself down. In any case, if you got 'connection refused', it isn't running. So there is nothing to shut down. So you don't have a problem.

Comment: http://172.22.68.60:8080/  getting below error in browser                                                                
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://nap11rh6as510:8006 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://172.22.68.60:8082 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

There is some Application running on port 8005 due to which tomcat is not able to bind network on the port. Your shutdown.sh will throw exception because server is not started yet (as there was an issue in starting the server)

- Solution 1(Recommended): Change the port from 8005 to 8006 in /opt/tomcat8/conf/server.xml
- Solution 2: Please check which application is using 8005 by `netstat -tulnp | grep 8005` and turn it off.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried by changing 8005 to 8006 in server.xml. But the same error occur with 8006.

Comment: Also I am getting below output for "netstat -tulnp | grep 8005"                                            (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      15268/java

Comment: this means that your tomcat is running and is bound to 127.0.0.1:8005. Changing the ports again and again wont help. Your process id is 15268 in the above case. use the command `kill -9 15268` to force terminate tomcat and restart using `/TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start`. Cheers.

Comment: Solution 1(Recommended): Change the port from 8005 to 8006 in /opt/tomcat8/conf/server.xml - Worked for me.Thanks Harneet.

Comment: Windows users can try netstat -ano | findstr 8005 to see which process is using port 8005.

Answer (score 1):

if the timestamps are correct, it suggests that your tomcat startup failed around 23:00 and you tried to shutdown a non existing tomcat service at 11:00 hours

Comment: Server time difference in log

Answer (score 1):

try to start from ./catalina.sh run
is every thing is ok then it will come on screen
or it will show some error
 like in my case

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /root/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx512MB
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

change memory heap size then it will definately work

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /root/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.782 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 28 2017 10:30:11 UTC
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.23.0
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.808 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.809 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.809 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /root/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.809 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.809 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.810 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.810 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.810 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/conf/logging.properties
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.811 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.812 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
10-Oct-2017 02:28:13.812 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.306 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.518 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.551 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.558 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.568 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 4756 ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.869 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:15.870 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
10-Oct-2017 02:28:16.072 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/ROOT]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:18.435 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [2,362] ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:18.436 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/docs]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:18.540 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/docs] has finished in [89] ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:18.541 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/examples]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.151 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/examples] has finished in [1,611] ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.152 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/host-manager]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.320 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [168] ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.321 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/manager]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.438 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/webapps/manager] has finished in [117] ms
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.461 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.540 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Oct-2017 02:28:20.547 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4978 ms



^C10-Oct-2017 02:29:29.604 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:29.695 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:29.748 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:30.063 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:30.069 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:30.077 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
10-Oct-2017 02:29:30.094 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
[root@localhost bin]# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /root/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Tomcat started.
then again try to shutdown

```
from /bin# ./shutdown
[root@localhost bin]# ./shutdown.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /root/Desktop/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/bootstrap.jar:/root/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add 
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
in /etc/profile,then run
source /etc/profile
it is avalible for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.51cto.com/zero01/2053974.  I meet the same problem today. When i want to execute shudown.sh, the log shows that tomcat may not be running, and the connection to port 8005 is refused. When i use `netstat -atunp`, i find there is no process listening port 8005. So tomcat should fail to start. I search,and find the answer in the link showed below. The key is to change `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`. The data to change is to add char 'u' before 'random':

`securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom`

Or set `-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom` in Tomcat's CATALINA_OPTS.

and it works. This helps in a specific scenario of an incomplete Tomcat start up resulting from some operation blocking in '/dev/random' reads in the event of low system entropy.  The Tomcat shutdown port is only listening after a full start up, so if a start attempt hangs in a '/dev/random' read or due to any other issue, the shutdown port is not listening and a shutdown attempt relying on it fails with the connection refused error.  If start up hangs in '/dev/random', then the urandom change addresses this as /dev/urandom never blocks and hangs waiting for system entropy.

A CATALINA_PID may be set to shutdown Tomcat using a pid file and OS signal without issue in this event instead of the shutdown port.